# YII_ENV_TEST in Acceptance tests

Tags: yii2, codeception, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to add acceptance tests to my project and everything was going smoothly until I tried to test form with captcha field.

Problem is I can't get set `YII_ENV_TEST` and `YII_ENV` contants so captcha always would be "testme" in tests.

I'm using PhpBrowser in `tests/acceptance.suite.yml`

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
```

So can I set YII_ENV somewhere so PhpBrowser would understand that I'm running tests?

Comment: For now I'm checking  `?test` param in url in my yii config file. If it's there I'm setting `YII_ENV` to `test`. Hope there is something more beautiful :D

Comment: why dont you simply start with http://localhost/<yiiapp>/web/index-test.php  , it has testing vars populated. All test-urls will change slightly

Comment: thanks @arkoak , i changed my codeception yaml config `PhpBrowser:` `url:` to include **index-test.php** and looks like that worked. Thanks!